# search for a child by id

Tags: javascript, html

there is html markup:

```
<div class="answer answer_one">
    <div class="pictures">
        <div id="0" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
        <div id="1" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i1.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
        <div id="2" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i2.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="discriptions">
        <div class="description description1" id="0">bus</div>
        <div class="description description2" id="1">car</div>
        <div class="description description3" id="2">plane</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="answer two hidden">
    <div class="pictures">
        <div id="0" id="picture" class="picture_two picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question2\\i.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
        </div>
        <div id="1" id="picture" class="picture_two picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question2\\i1.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
        </div>
        <div id="2" id="picture" class="picture_two picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question2\\i2.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
        </div>
        <div id="3" id="picture" class="picture_two picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question2\\i3.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
        </div>
        <div id="4" id="picture" class="picture_two picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question2\\i4.jpg" width=200px height=200px>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="discriptions">
        <div class="description description1" id="0">aaa</div>
        <div class="description description2" id="1">bbbb</div>
        <div class="description description3" id="2">gggg</div>
        <div class="description description4" id="3">ttttt</div>
        <div class="description description5" id="4">eeee</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js code that when you click on one of the pictures turns it black. How to make sure that when you click, an element from descriptions with the same id is still output to the console:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < option.length; i++) {
    option[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var target = e.target.closest('.picture');
        if(target) {
            let old = this.querySelector('.picture.active');
            if(old) old.classList.remove('active');
            target.classList.add('active');
        }
        console.log(target)
    })
}
```

I can't think of anything

Comment: There should be only one id attribute per element and each id needs to be unique!

Comment: @Mani how to make then that when you click on the first picture, the first description is displayed ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question in the thread above:

> how to make then that when you click on the first picture, the first description is displayed ?

Instead of using id's you can use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*), for example:

When you click on an image with `data-trigger="1"`, you can get this value in JS -> [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

And then you can select the related description with the same data attribute value, e.g. `data-content="1"` and add/remove/toggle class which changes visibility.

```
// "value" is the data-trigger attribute value, in this case = 1

const description = document.querySelector(`[data-content="${value}"]`);

description.classList.remove('is-hidden');
```